Assertion 'clusters_fit_into_fat(Fs)' failed error in makefile. What to do?
So, newbie here. I've recently started a series by this YouTube named Poncho for OSdev, and tried following the instructions given in this video https://youtu.be/mpPbKEeWIHU?si=mReByNiwfk6W4Xlu. Now I'm getting this error, and I've no idea what the hell it means. Any help?
P.S. I've not tried anything not shown in the linked video.
